# how do i loop through a char array being passed to a function and return number of chars

Tags: c, readline

```
#include "Definition.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ExternalVar.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int Readline(),CountWord(),CountsUpdate();


char Line[MaxLine];  /* one line from the file */


int NChars = 0,  /* number of characters seen so far */
    NWords = 0,  /* number of words seen so far */
    NLines = 0,  /* number of lines seen so far */
    LineLength;  /* length of the current line */ 

int wc = 0,
    lc = 0,
    cc = 0,
    tc = 0;


int i;

main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp= fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (fp) 
    {
        while (i=fscanf(fp,"%s",Line)!=EOF)
        ///printf("%s \n",Line);
        cc=Readline(Line);
        printf("%d \n",cc);
        fclose(fp);


    }
    return 0;  
}
```

This is my main function I am passing the char array Line[] to the function Readline(Line) and I want it to return the number of chars in the array.

Here is the function Readline.c . No matter which text file I use as the argument I keep getting 84 as the returning value. Not sure what I am doing wrong or right since I am new to C programming. Please help.

```
#include "Definition.h"
#include "ExternalVar.h"
#include <stdio.h>



int Readline(char *Line)
{   
int i;


for (i = 0; Line[i] == '\n' ; i++)
{

return i;
}
}
```

Output is as folllows

taj@taj:~/Desktop/2014_Summer_CIS5027_Asg2$ gcc Main.c Readline.c 
taj@taj:~/Desktop/2014_Summer_CIS5027_Asg2$ ./a.out b.txt

84

Comment: `Line[i] == '\n'` : wrong condition. It write a condition to continue the loop. and `return i;` move to after loop.

Comment: ok I moved Line[i] == '\n' to after the loop but now it returns value 1. What do I replace the condition with?

#include "Definition.h"

#include "ExternalVar.h"

#include <stdio.h>




int Readline(char *Line)

{ 

int i;


for (i = 0; i != 0  ; i++)

{


i++;

return *Line;

}

Line[i] == '\n';


}

Comment: you misunderstand that i said. i post sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You have few problems:

1) You probably want to check until you hit `\n`. So the condition should really be:

```
for (i = 0; Line[i] != '\n' ; i++)
```

2) Your input may not contain `\n`. So you should also check whether you have reached the end of the string:

```
for (i = 0; Line[i] && Line[i] != '\n' ; i++)
```

3) What if the first character is `\n` in `Line`? It won't enter the loop at all and you are not returning anything in that case. So you should initialize `i=0` and return it. You could rewrite the function as:

```
int Readline(char *Line)
{   
int i = 0;

  for (i = 0; Line[i] && Line[i] != '\n' ; i++)
  {
  ;
  }

return i;
}
```

4)`fscanf()` with `%s` format doesn't read `\n` even if your input file contains it. You probably want to use `fgets()` to read which does read the `\n` chars:

```
while (fgets(Line, sizeof Line, fp)) {
  ...
}
```

5) main() function should return an `int`: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {... }`

Comment: Ok I changed Main to implement fgets instead and tried using the code you posted, but its returning 0 every time no matter which txt file I put into the argument.

Comment: That `break` reverses the logic. Try it without the `break` statement in the for loop as in the answer now.

Comment: I didn't use the break statement. I used what you posted.

Comment: hmm...did you use `Line[i] != `\n` as well in the loop condition?

Comment: ok this is what I did

int Readline(char *Line)
{   
int i = 0;

  for (i = 0; Line[i] && Line[i] != '\n' ; i++)
  {
  
  }

return i;
}

I got 15 back as which includes the chars on the line and spaces. However, when I try a different text file I get 0 .

Comment: What's that text where it produces incorrect result?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I believe OP is using `fgets` instead.

Comment: the first text file was just:

My name is Tomy
My name is Tomy
My name is Tomy

The second txt file was
This is a Test
This is a Test
This is a Test

The first file was returning 15 whereas the second one returned 0. Yes I was using fgets

Comment: It depends on `MAXLINE`. If it's not long enough to read a whole line, fgets() will continue from where it stopped for the previous line.

Comment: I see, well maxline is defined as 200 in the def.h file

Answer (score 0):

```
int Readline(char *Line){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; Line[i] != '\0' ; i++)//newline is not included in the Line. Because read by fscanf(fp,"%s",Line)
        ;

    return i;
}
```